# Adding field with sample data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm creating sql query to get specific records back.
I need to have records with columns site_name;device_name, where I list all the sites with one sample device for each site.

t1: view_building_custom_fields_flat_v1 with fields: building_fk, site_name

t2: view_building_v1 with fields: building_pk, device_fk

t3: view_device_v1 with fields: device_pk, building_fk, device_name

t1 is a helper table for t2 so the relation is one to one, but building has multiple devices so relation is one to many.

I have build a query that is listing all the devices for each building so far:

```sql
SELECT
 view_building_custom_fields_flat_v1.site_name,
 view_device_v1.device_name
FROM view_building_custom_fields_flat_v1
INNER JOIN view_building_v1 ON view_building_custom_fields_flat_v1.building_fk=view_building_v1.building_pk
INNER JOIN view_device_v1 ON view_building_v1.building_pk=view_device_v1.building_fk
ORDER BY view_building_custom_fields_flat_v1.site_name ASC
```

I know that with my code I cannot expect nothing else, but I would be great if anyone could help me to modify it to meet my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one row per `site_name`, you can use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (cff.site_name) cff.site_name, d.device_name
FROM view_building_custom_fields_flat_v1 cff JOIN 
     view_building_v1 b
     ON cff.building_fk = b.building_pk JOIN
     view_device_v1 d
     ON b.building_pk = d.building_fk
ORDER BY cff.site_name ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems complicated. I need to test it first :-)

Comment: ok, I've tested it and it works. I is not complicated anymore as I understood how works DISTINCT ON - thank!